# RequireJS + BackboneJS - connect modules

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a problem when I try to connect two modules containing two different views of BackboneJS.

In this module of RequireJS contains a view of backbone. 
I need within this module, refer to another view of backbone that is in another module. 
I modified the code to make it simpler

```
define (["jquery","backbone","collections/controlSearchCollection","views/currentPlaylist","jqueryUI"], function($, Backbone, controlSearchMusic, currentPlaylist){

var searchModule = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#containerSearch",

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new controlSearchMusic();
    },
    events:{
        "dblclick li":"select"
    },
    select: function(element){
        var trackJSON ={};
        trackJSON["id"]= "playCloud_"+$(element.target).attr("id");
        currentPlaylist.collection.add(trackJSON);   <--- Here is where this error

    }
});

return searchModule;
});
```

Here, my other module of RequireJS containing a view of backboneJS. i need add to JSON from the first module.

```
define (["jquery","backbone","collections/controlCurrentPlaylistCollection","jqueryUI"], function($, Backbone, controlCurrentPlaylist){

    var currentPlaylist = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#currentPlaylist",

        initialize: function(){
            this.collection = new controlCurrentPlaylist();
            this.collection.on("add", this.executeFunction, this);

        },
        executeFunction: function(song){
            alert(song.toSource());
        }
    });
    return currentPlaylist;
});
```

the two modules are instantiated in app.js

Someone can help me? Thanks you!

Comment: Maybe you should test in Chrome and set breakpoints in the second module. Are you there are no errors while loading the modules?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering so quickly.
There are no errors in the loading of modules. the error is that does not refer to the object currentPlaylist. the firebug tells me that CurrentePlaylist is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the exact error its hard to tell but it looks like you don't have created an instance of `currentPlaylist`. So `currentPlaylist.collection` is undefined and causing an error when your try to call the `add` function on it.

You can try this:

```
var cpl = new currentPlaylist(); // create instance
cpl.collection.add(trackJSON);  // cpl.collection should be initialized here
```

Comment: Hi micha, I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly but I emerged to doubt.
Does this way don't do the module dependent that starts the first? i need the two independent modules.

thanks for answering so quickly.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do exactly. If you want to use the `currentPlaylist` view in another module with different data you can just create another instance of `currentPlaylist`. If you want that multiple modules can access the same view instance (with the same data) you can create the instance inside your `currentPlaylist` module and return the instance instead of the definition.

Comment: I had seen that on several occasions returning the instance, but did not know that this served to that can be used for multiple views can use the same data. It is precisely what I need.
It has helped me a lot what you told me. Thank you very much